# How to filter DOMRange in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I want to filter a DOMRange in JavaScript so that it only contains span elements or #text but I can't find a way to do it.

code: `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) and tagName

```
.filter(node => node.nodeType===Node.TEXTNODE || 
  (node.nodeType===Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.tagName==="SPAN"))
```

Comment: How can I get the array of elements from the Range? Array.from doesn't work here

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment

Comment: You can (also) do something like `const div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = yourRange;` and parse that